# Problema al realizar deploy en Heroku

Tags: nodejs, heroku

EStoy intentado realizar un deploy de una page a heroku una que antes ya le habia realizado deploy y funcionaba pero esta ves no deja de salir problemas y no encuentro cual es el problema

Yo se que muestra un claro error de que no encuentra el models/Report, pero este esta bien exportado y debe verlo.

El modelo solo es utilizado para realizar una consulta en una base de datos MongoDB usando mongoose.

El procfile ya lo he agregado.

En local sirve perfectamente sin warnings ni errores.

Esto es lo que me manda el heroku logs -tails

```
E:\ingeniotic\FRONT\panic-js>heroku logs --app panic-web
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016636+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016640+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016642+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016645+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/Report'
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016646+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016649+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/src/routes/notes.js
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016651+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/src/index.js
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016653+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016655+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016658+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016660+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016662+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/routes/notes.js:9:16)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016664+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016666+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016668+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016670+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016672+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016674+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016676+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/index.js:52:9)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016678+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016680+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016682+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016684+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14) {
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016686+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2019-11-20T18:08:21.016687+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/src/routes/notes.js', '/app/src/index.js' ]
2019-11-20T18:25:36.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user fnsk1999@gmail.com
2019-11-20T18:25:57.242831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-11-20T18:25:56.972281+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 47dfebc7 by user fnsk1999@gmail.com
2019-11-20T18:25:56.972281+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user fnsk1999@gmail.com
2019-11-20T18:25:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-11-20T18:25:59.455256+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command node src/index.js
2019-11-20T18:26:01.733846+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-11-20T18:26:01.738843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-11-20T18:26:01.651211+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2019-11-20T18:26:01.651242+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2019-11-20T18:26:01.651244+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657053+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657073+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657075+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657078+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657080+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/Report'
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657081+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657088+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/src/routes/map.js
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657090+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/src/index.js
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657096+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657098+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657101+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657103+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657105+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/routes/map.js:7:14)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657107+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657108+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657110+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657112+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)        
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657114+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657116+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)       
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657117+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/index.js:52:9)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657119+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657121+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657123+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657125+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14) {
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657127+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657129+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/src/routes/map.js', '/app/src/index.js' ]
2019-11-20T18:26:01.657131+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2019-11-20T18:26:01.711568+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-11-20T18:26:04.614245+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command node src/index.js
2019-11-20T18:26:07.807529+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-11-20T18:26:07.791955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-11-20T18:26:07.713863+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2019-11-20T18:26:07.713894+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2019-11-20T18:26:07.713896+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721496+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721501+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721674+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721677+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721679+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/Report'
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721682+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721684+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/src/routes/map.js
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721686+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/src/index.js
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721689+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721690+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721693+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721695+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721697+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/routes/map.js:7:14)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721699+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721701+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721703+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721706+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721708+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721710+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721712+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/index.js:52:9)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721714+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721717+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721719+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721721+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14) {
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721724+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721726+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/src/routes/map.js', '/app/src/index.js' ]
2019-11-20T18:26:07.721728+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2019-11-20T18:27:24.599482+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=panic-web.herokuapp.com request_id=7a50208d-9031-4328-bfe4-225284915d59 fwd="186.83.94.187" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-11-20T18:27:27.059511+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=panic-web.herokuapp.com request_id=4b6909af-760f-491b-9fea-88ab766d4cac fwd="186.83.94.187" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Como estas haciendo el deploy? es un git push?

Comment: Con un git push